# iOS >> iPhone 5 vs. 4 >> How to Force the App to Have One Screen Size?

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-5, iphone-4

Let's say that when creating a new app, I wish to NOT adjust an app for both screens sizes (5 vs. 4); instead I wish to design one screen that suits iPhone 4 (and lower) and have these black bars appear in both sides.

I do wish to use Auto Layout for other purposes.

Currently, If I design the screen in IB while it displays the 4 size and then run it on 5, it stretches the background view instead of adding the black bars.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be rejected, if you don't add iPhone 5 screen support. Apple won t accept new apps without iPhone 5 support.

> Apps that don't support Apple's latest iOS device displays are on
>   their way out, as are apps that haven't been updated to address a
>   longstanding privacy concern. On Thursday, Apple informed iOS App
>   developers that as of May 1, the App Store will stop accepting new
>   apps or app updates that access a device's unique identifier or fail
>   to support Retina devices and the iPhone 5.
>
> Starting May 1, Apple will require all iPhone apps to do so, as well
>   as support iOS devices with Retina displays in general.

Comment: No s**t!?!?!?! They are forcing me to design the app IB twice? or stumble through their Auto-Layout thing? As a freelancer, it means that I have to charge for the extra work! I cannot allow my customer to say "hey, I don't mind having these black bars for the first version to keep the budget lower". that sucks!

Comment: Yes, I recomend you to make your app from code, not from IB. I make everything from code, and because of this, my app fits on every screen. I m not using storyboard, or xib.

Comment: I know it's better to deal with it from code, but hey, what's the point of having this "amazing" tool that supposes to make the design much more intuitive if you don't use it. When working with graphic designers or when teaching new students with no programming background (which I do...) - using IB is mandatory. If it was just me, I might have not think twice; but it's not just me...

Comment: Well, auto-layout support has much improved in XCode 5, although I still find it easier to define constraints in code...

Comment: You don't need AutoLayout to make you interface grow with the screen size, old style view autoresize mask will also do.